# Why does the variable c print as 3 when it should print 4?

Tags: c, while-loop

X is a decimal that enters a bunch of loops that keep subtracting certain decimals from it and c is an integer that increments by one every time an operation happens. Four operations should happen but the last loop terminates early and the c never increments from 3 to 4. The last while loop keeps terminating early?

```
int main(void) {

float x = 0.41;

int c = 0;

while(x >= 0.25)
{
    x-= 0.25;

    c++;
}

while(x >= 0.1)
{
    x-= 0.1;

    c++;
}

while(x >= 0.05)
{
    x-= 0.05;

    c++;
}

while(x >= 0.01)
{
    c++;

    x-= 0.01;
}

printf("%i", c);

}
```

Comment: the last loop is a typo it should say while(x >= 0.01).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floats in C are not absolutely precise. They have 23 bits to actually represent the actual value. When you write

```
float x = 0.41
```

The actual representation of the value in the float value is slightly different from `exactly` 0.41, depending on your computer architecture/compiler.

To see for yourself, add the following line to each of your loop blocks:

```
printf("%d, %.30f\n", c, x);
```

On my machine, I get

```
1, 0.159999999999999975575093458247
2, 0.059999999999999970023978335121
3, 0.009999999999999967248420773558
```

Comparisons with floats in C should be handled with epsilon values for these discrepancies. In your case, you should allow the compared values to have be within a bound of the target value. Something like

```
#include <math.h>
...
while(fabs(x-0.01f) < 0.000001) //check that x is within a certain range of 0.01
```

Reference on the topic: http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Comment: thanks i didn't realize such a small difference can cause such a big problem.

Comment: Another option is to not use floats at all, and use integers

Comment: This has nothing to do with C. It's a representation problem coming from the IEEE floating point standard. [read here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(x >= 0.05)
{
    x-= 0.05;
    c++;
}

while(x >= 0.1)
{
    c++;
    x-= 0.01;
}
```

try Switching these to these

```
while(x >= 0.1)
{
    c++;
    x-= 0.01;
}
while(x >= 0.05)
{
    x-= 0.05;
    c++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exact comparisons don't mix with finite precision. It's precisely the same reason if you represent 1/3 with some number of decimal digits (0.3333333), you'll need to add it to zero *four* times before it's greater than or equal to one.